# Insert New Row using `With` instead of `.Select`

Tags: excel, vba, select, insert

I'm having trouble trying to use `with` instead of `.select` when writing code to insert a new row. I have been told multiple times that `.select` is not to be used as it is much slower.

My macro creates a new row but deletes the contents in the row below and copies the formatting of the row above which never happened when I was using `.select`. This also means that the increasing number in cell B11 is not correct as it starts again from 1 due to the cleared contents below.

```
Sub New_Entry()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B11:AB11")

With rng
.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With rng
.ClearContents
.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With

With Range("B11")
    .Value = Range("B12") + 1
End With

With rng
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Font.TintAndShade = 0
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think its cause your setting it to b12's value, should b12 be set to b11+1?

Comment: The numbering works when using `.select` with the same values. The numbering increases up the sheet so that b12 would be 1 and b11 would be 2 etc as new rows are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range "rng" seems to shift down after the insert. Here is the route I would take:

```
Sub New_Entry()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("B11:AB11").Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Range("B11").Value = Range("B12") + 1

    With Range("B11:AB11")
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Font.TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you have two questions:

**1. Why does this delete the content?**

That is because your `With rng` takes `Set rng = Range("B11:AB11")` and does `.ClearContents` to it *at the same time as it inserts a row.*

You can check this by switching around the order of your code.
All `With` statements with the same condition always run at the same time.

**2. Why is the formatting copied?**

The format isn't actually copied, you are formatting every line you create with `.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous`.

This should work:

```
Sub New_Entry()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B11:AB11")

With rng
'.ClearContents
.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
'.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
'End With

'With rng
.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With Range("B11")
    .Value = Range("B12") + 1
End With

With rng
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Font.TintAndShade = 0
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

`.Select` is slower because it runs code line by line.

Comment: Thanks, this almost works but still changes the second row as the `with rng` happens all at once so the inserted row isn't changed. That's probably my fault for not being more clear in my question.